# Relay Can't Bind Tor to Port 9050

Tags: configuration, relays

I'm setting up a relay on Ubuntu 14.04 using the instructions here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu.

My config is super small and basic:

```
ORPort 9050
DirPort 9030
RelayBandwidthRate 770 KB
RelayBandwidthBurst 1540 KB
Nickname coolrelaynamedawg
ContactInfo David <huertanix@nycresistor.com>
AccountingMax 1999 GB
AccountingStart month 1 12:00
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

When I edited /etc/tor/torrc with the aforementioned config and ran `sudo service tor restart` I got:

```
Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:9050. Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
```

Running `ps aux | grep tor` doesn't show that the Tor process is running.

This server is a fresh DigitalOcean Ubuntu VPS and doesn't have a web server or anything installed. Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Use`netstat -tulpan | grep "9050"` to see which program is using the port. Try killing Tor and then starting it again. Did you try any other ports (a higher number)?

Comment: I was able to solve this by changing the ORPort to 9001, which is the default for ORPort. I had mistakenly thought that 9050 was the ORPort default when it was in fact the SOCKS port.